# Function that take date and return the statement of the validation of the date

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector

Write a function called **valid_date** that takes three positive integer scalar inputs **year**, **month**, **day**. If these three represent a valid date, return a logical **true**, otherwise **false**. The name of the output argument is **valid**. If any of the inputs is not a positive integer scalar, return **false** as well. Note that every year that is exactly divisible by 4 is a leap year, except for years that are exactly divisible by 100. However, years that are exactly divisible by 400 are also leap years. For example, the year 1900 was not leap year, but the year 2000 was. Note that your solution must not contain any of the date related built-in MATLAB functions.

samples:

```
valid = valid_date(2018,4,1)
valid = valid_date(2018,4,31)
```

The outputs are :

```
valid = 
  logical 
     1 

valid = 
  logical 
     0
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
function out= valid_date(y,m,d)

if mod(y,4)==0
    if mod (y,100)==0
        if mod(y,400)==0
            leap =true;
        else
            leap=false;
        end
    else
        leap =true;
    end
else
    leap= false;
end 

if y>0 &m>0&d>0 &y==fix(y)&m==fix(m)&d==fix(d)&m<=12 &isscalar(y)&isscalar(m)& isscalar(d)

if (m==1 | m==3|m==5|m==7 |m==8 |m==10 |m==12)&d <=31
        out=true;
    elseif d<=30
        if m==2 
            if leap==true & d<=29
                out =true;
            elseif leap==false &d<=28
                out=true;
            else
                out=false;
            end
        else
            out=true;
        end
else
    out =false;
    end
else
    out= false;
end
```

Comment: This section is for answer only, post the code in original post

Comment: @Adam  It is the answer of my question.. :)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @Adam My question is  how to write a function that checks if the date is valid or not ..

Comment: I guess, what @Adam wants to point out: Why do you post the question in the first place, when you're answering it right after? That's the second time, see [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56455160). If you want to have comments on the "quality" of your solution/code, there's a separate branch in the Stack Exchange network called [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). (Stack Overflow doesn't need a bunch of homework assignments...)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution:

```
function valid= valid_date(year,month,date)
if nargin~=3
    valid=false;
elseif ~isscalar(year) | ~isscalar(month) | ~isscalar(date)
    valid=false;
elseif year<1 || month<1 || date<1
    valid=false;
elseif  year~=fix(year) || month~=fix(month) || date~=fix(date)
    valid=false;
elseif month>12 || date>31
    valid=false;

elseif month==2
        if (rem(year,400)==0 || (rem(year,4)==0 && rem(year,100)~=0)) && date<30
            valid=true;
        elseif (rem(year,400)~=0 || (rem(year,4)~=0 && rem(year,100)==0)) && date<29
           
                valid=true;
            else
                valid=false;
        
        end
else
    days = [31 29 31 30  31 30 31 31 30 31 30 31];
    totaldays = days(month);
    if date>totaldays
        valid=false;
    else
        valid=true;
    end
end
end
```